# function with loop that goes through columns of dataframes with different dimensions

Tags: function

Writing loops are the bane of my existence. 
I have this function, which works:

rnd.data<-function(x){ 
  min.x<-min(x[,2]) 
  max.x<-max(x[,2]) 
  min.y<-min(x[,3]) 
  max.y<-max(x[,3]) 
  data.table(x = runif(34, min.x, max.x))[, y := runif(34, min.y, max.y)] 
}

it's purpose is to simulate data within parameters that are dependent on the column of the dataframe in question 
for the first data set I wrote it for had only 2 columns I wanted to simulate samples for 
however i have additional dataframes with different numbers of columns 
ideally i would write one function with a for loop that could compute samples for all dataframes I want to input as I need to simulate more than 1000 samples per dataframe

I tired manipulating the beginning to read as: 
rnd2.data<-function(x){ 
  n<-dim(x)[2] 
  for(i in 1:n){ 
    if(n > 3){ 
but then got stuck as to what to do next

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This function allows you to do it without looping:

```
ff<-function(x,r){
  apply(x,2,function(z) do.call(runif,as.list(c(r,range(z)))))
}

> set.seed(123)
> x<-cbind(1:10,11:20,51:60)
> ff(x,10)
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
 [1,] 3.588198 19.61150 59.00585
 [2,] 8.094746 15.08001 57.23523
 [3,] 4.680792 17.09814 56.76456
 [4,] 8.947157 16.15370 59.94843
 [5,] 9.464206 11.92632 56.90135
 [6,] 1.410008 19.09842 57.37677
 [7,] 5.752949 13.21479 55.89659
 [8,] 9.031771 11.37854 56.34728
 [9,] 5.962915 13.95129 53.60244
[10,] 5.109533 19.59053 52.32402
>
```

If you want to ignore some columns, just call, for example `ff(x[,-1],10)` or `ff(x[,2:3],10)`, etc.

If you want to apply this to a list of dataframes, then you can call

```
lapply(listOfData,ff,numberOfSamples)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I keep getting an error message : Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'rnd.data(x)' is not a function, character or symbol

Comment: There's no `rnd.data(x)` in the code I wrote.  What are you trying to execute that gives you that error?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. I apologize, I modified it incorrectly. It works like a dream. Thanks!